# How to filter csv with matplotlib using dates on the x-axis and rainfall on the y-axis?

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file with all two columns one that says 'Date' and the other that has the rainfall amount in inches called 'Rainfall'. I am not sure how to go about this, so far my approach has not been working. I also need to skip the first 5 lines before I enter into the 'Date' and 'Rainfall' column.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv

x = []
y = []

with open('1541553208_et.csv','r') as csvfile:
    plots = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in plots:
        for i in row:
            x.append(row[0])
            y.append(row[1])


plt.plot(x,y, label='Loaded from file!')
plt.xlabel('Dates')
plt.ylabel('Evaporation (inches)')
plt.title('Eden_7')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

When I run the code I get the following incorrect results:

[image]

I want to have it so that each months rainfall data is clustered into one

Here is an example of what I am going on:
[image]

I am trying to get the same effect as the top. How could this be done?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You may have a simpler time using the `pandas` library instead of the `csv` library.

For instance, pandas allows you to store the csv file directly into a data structure called a *dataframe*. This will allow you to group on dates or rainfall and plot the data.

```
import pandas as pd
# rain will be an dataframe instance
rain = pd.read_csv(csvfile)
rain = rain.groupby(rain['rainfall'])
rain.plot(kind='bar')
plt.show()
```

Play around with it, pandas is very powerful.

You can find the `pandas` documentation here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/

While this may not be an immediate solution, it may help in the long run.

Comment: Thank you. How would I range the y-axis from 0.0 to 3.0 and the x-axis from January to December? also not sure how to populate the graph with 'Date' and 'Rainfall' data. I replaced csvfile with my csv and got KeyError: 'rainfall'.

Answer (score 0):

Using pandas library will be easier as previously mentioned. Following your csv library can you try to run this,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv

x = []
y = []
f = open('1541553208_et.csv')
csv_f = csv.reader(f,delimiter=',')
for row in csv_f:
    x.append(row[0])
for row in csv_f:
    y.append(row[1])

plt.plot(x,y, label='Loaded from file!')
plt.xlabel('Dates')
plt.ylabel('Evaporation (inches)')
plt.title('Eden_7')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you. It's giving me this error:x.append(row[0])……..IndexError: list index out of range. I think this has something to do with the way my csv file is set up because the first 4 lines are just some text and not the actual data. Here is what that looks like: https://imgur.com/a/wpBVWSy

Comment: yeah the strings are creating problem. you have to ways to solve that, first is taking all data in a separate file if you use only one csv file, and the second one is creating another extra loop to read data from the specific column.